# Pagination based on date in meteor, similar to Product Hunt

Tags: meteor, pagination

I'm following along with the Discover Meteor.js book and creating the link sharing app but want to do pagination based based on week instead of by post recency.

Currently the code is structured to show a certain number of posts based on the URL: http://localhost:3000/<#ofDisplayedPosts>

But I want to display every post submitted in the most recent week, followed by the previous week, etc.

Here's the publication of the posts mongo collection:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(options){
  check(options, {
    sort: Object,
    limit: Number,
  });
  return Posts.find({}, options);
});
```

And here is how the router passes the data to the client

```
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'postsList',
  increment: 5,
  postsLimit: function() {
    return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
  },
  findOptions: function() {
    return {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: this.postsLimit()};
  },
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
  },
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
  },
  data: function() {
    var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
    var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment});
    return {
      posts: this.posts(),
      ready: this.postsSub.ready,
      nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
    };
  }
});
```

Similar to Product Hunt, How can I group posts by week, encode that information into the URL & create a link at the bottom of the page to view the previous week's posts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic process:

1. Replace your route parameter `:numberOfDisplayedPosts` with `:startdate` so that your route knows what date to use as a starting point. For even more flexibility you could use two route parameters, startdate and enddate and then you could look at weeks, days, months or whatever.
2. Remove all references to `limit` as you're only going to be using date ranges.
3. Compute start and end datetimes based on your route parameter(s). Note that mongodb stores datetimes in UTC.
4. Use those datetimes in your query to select within a date range.
5. Compute the parameter(s) required for the next/previous page routes.
6. You also have to essentially run the next/previous page queries to see if there's any data there because there's no way to tell if you've reached the end or not. Alternatively you can use the min/max datetimes to figure it out.
7. Do sorts on the client, not the server, unless you're trying to get the min or max of the whole collection.